# "Немногие" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Разгорелся спор вокруг вот этой картинки (уже не знаю, мотиватор или это демотиватор). Как вы считаете, "не()многие" в данном случае пишется слитно или раздельно?

[image]

Картинка взята отсюда: http://vk.com/love_russian_language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из словаря: НЕМНОГИЕ - некоторые (возможно, избранные),  НЕ МНОГИЕ  -незначительный по количеству ряд людей, так что смысловые оттенки  разные.

Рассмотрим слитное написание: НЕМНОГИЕ(некоторые) поймут - как-то неуклюже звучит,  фраза незаконченная. Да и по структуре это типично отрицательная конструкция с частицей НЕ в начале предложения, которая обычно выделяется логически. Поэтому надо писать раздельно: НЕ МНОГИЕ ПОЙМУТ. Если же требуется выразить утвердительный смысл, желательно изменить структуру предложения, например: "поймут немногие", но и это не название.

Comment: >София: НЕМНОГИЕ - некоторые (возможно, избранные), НЕ МНОГИЕ -незначительный по количеству ряд людей,

1) да!
2) нет! НЕ МНОГИЕ — это отрицание, это не декларация незначительности, а это предупреждение во избежание ошибочной у читателя коннотации большинства!

Comment: Давайте попробуем применить синонимы. Получаются примерные два варианта: "избранные (немногие) поймут, избранные (немногие) вспомнят" и "мало кто поймет, мало кто вспомнит". Что хотел сказать автор? Чтобы узнать, наверное, надо посмотреть фильм.

Comment: Хм... Я воспринял картинку как баннер, как кадр из фильма. Если же сам фильм так называется, то, конечно, надо смотреть.

Да уж, ведусь я частенько на нынешние лапидарные вопросики...

Comment: Может, кадр и из фильма, но сама фраза гуляет в "Одноклассниках" именно в таком написании. Ею подписывают фотографию из 70-80-х с приметами того времени. Мне хочется видеть здесь слитное написание: немногие=мало кто. Но автор имеет право выбирать написание, соответствующее его замыслу.

Comment: Кажется, это общее название для творческих зарисовок, так что авторов много. Это девиз, причем можно увидеть его разные варианты: "не многие поймут, не все вспомнят" и "немногие (=избранные) поймут, но многие вспомнят.

Comment: Сам фильм называется "Десятое королевство". Был такой сказочный сериал лет двадцать назад. Очень неплохой, кстати.

Comment: Кстати, при изменении формы написания может меняться и смысл названия, то есть тема зарисовки: (1)"не многие поймут, не все вспомнят" - здесь речь идет о количестве помнящих и понимающих, (2)"немногие (= только избранные) поймут, но многие вспомнят - здесь "понять" и "вспомнить" противопоставлены друг другу.

Answer (score 5):

Я вижу здесь отрицание,значит, раздельно, всё верно.

Смысл не в том, что какие-то немногие поймут и вспомнят, а в том,что это сделают далеко не все и далеко не  многие,

Comment: Я вообще не вижу. Она у меня не открывается:(

Answer (score 0):

Если это отрицание, то какой смысл экспозиции в целом? Как бы это сказать иначе... К чему коннотацию сожаления о забытом возводить в предикат?
За слитное написание: это утверждение о памяти, пусть даже в мозгах немногих.

Сам же я эту картинку первый раз вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста.
  Есть правила написания НЕ с  прилагательными.
----Слитно-если можно   заменить синонимами без НЕ.
---- Раздельно -  если  есть противопоставление двух понятий
ПРИМЕРЫ: 
Немногие справились   "Немногие" можно заменить единицы, мало кто...) 
Не многие, а только избранные.

Comment: Контекст перед Вами. К чему повторять всем общие правила? То, что эта фраза — название фильма, уже о многом говорит! Рассуждайте, как рассуждают Людмила, София, Hermit.

Answer (score -1):

Здесь -- слитно. Раздельно пишется, когда есть возражение. Например: *не многие, а только некоторые...*

Comment: Вы частично правы, но только частично. Есть еще несколько случаев, когда предпочтительно раздельное написание. Но главное это то, что правило ваше - не императивное, оно лишь "подсвечивает" суть. "Немногие" - это *некоторые*. "Не многие" - это просто отрицание ко "многие". Может быть, что и все, а может и никто. Здесь же - полное авторское право написать как слитно, так и раздельно - в зависимости от смысла.